# Web layout and size units

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

I have problem with understanding how to create a website's layout. If I use `vh` and `vw` units for my `body` height/width, I'm unable to zoom in/out. I also heard about problems with viewport units in mobile browsers.

How should a website's layout be made. Using only percentages and pixels + media queries?

Comment: It all depends on the effect you want to create. If you want to be able to pinch zoom, then yes, don't use size units that adjust themselves to the width of the viewport. Or, don't use <meta name="viewport"...

Comment: Where should viewport units be used?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to look at the ***Flexbox*** and the ***Grid*** as they are the future of responsive web development. Besides, a good practice is to use a combination of both, `px` and `%`, alongside `@media` queries.

Comment: Frameworks can also make your life easy, with bootstrap grid system you can create good responsive layout. Great answer, Using all of them altogether gives you a good responsive experience.